# angular 2 changing my service in order to take my rest api from my backend

Tags: node.js, rest, api, angular

So I about to exchange my array so it take a rest api from my node backend but I'm not sure how to convert my service so it does that or the modules that are need in order to do so. Like what things i'm I supposed to import for it. The service works with the site currently but want to exchange the array for the rest api when node is running.

angular 2 service

```
/**
 * Created by g62 on 23/01/17.
 */
export interface Article {
    // Unique Id
    id: string;
    // Ref on category belongs to
    categoryId: string;
    //genre
    genre: string;
    // The title
    title: string;
    // Price
    rating: number;
    //director
    director: string;
    //cast
    cast: string;
    //production
    production: string;
    // Description
    description: string;
    // Plot
    plot: string;
    //opinion
    opinion: string;
    // Mark article with special rating
    isSpecial: boolean;
    // Path to small image
    imageS: string;
    // Path to large image
    imageL: string;
}

export class ArticleService {
// basic want to change this part so it accepts the rest api which is localhost:3000/api/article or something like that
    private articles: Article[] = [
        // Bakery
        { id: '1', categoryId: '1', title: 'Lion King', rating: 1.5, isSpecial: false, imageL: 'http://placehold.it/1110x480', imageS: 'http://placehold.it/270x171', director: 'some guy at disney', description: 'It a great movie about talking animals', plot:'disney plot', opinion:'one of my favorite movies', production: 'how was it made' },
        { id: '2', categoryId: '1', title: 'Big Hero 6', rating: 5, isSpecial: false, imageL: 'http://placehold.it/1110x480', imageS: 'http://placehold.it/270x171', description: 'It a movie about six kids and a puffy robot', plot:'disney plot', opinion:'my favorite movie in 2015',production: 'how was it made' },
        { id: '3', categoryId: '1', title: 'Lilo and Stitch', rating: 7, isSpecial: false, imageL: 'http://placehold.it/1110x480', imageS: 'http://placehold.it/270x171', description: 'A disney movie that takes place on Hawaii', plot:'disney plot', opinion:'my favorite disney movie',production: 'how was it made' }

    ];

    getArticles(category?: string, search?: string) {
        if (category) {
            return this.articles.filter((article: Article, index: number, array: Article[]) => {
                return article.categoryId === category;
            });
        } else if (search) {
            let lowSearch = search.toLowerCase();
            return this.articles.filter((article: Article, index: number, array: Article[]) => {
                return article.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowSearch) != -1;
            });
        } else {
            return this.articles;
        }
    }

    getArticle(id: string): Article {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.articles.length; i++) {
            if (this.articles[i].id === id) {
                return this.articles[i];
            }
        }
        throw new ArticleNotFoundException(`Article ${id} not found`);
    }
}

export class ArticleNotFoundException extends Error {
    constructor(message?: string) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace your static articles with ones from the back end. If that's the case, try something like this:

```
private articles: Article[];

getArticles(): Observable<Article[]> {
    const url = `localhost:3000/api/article`;
    return this.http.get(url)
               .map(response => response.json() as Article[] )
               .subscribe(articles => this.articles = articles)
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

That said, it's your backend that generally filter or return specific item within its id. I don't know why you are filtering yourself in the front but you have certainly your reasons ...

Comment: thank you, I was just experimenting with filters in angular 2 and that part is going to be changed.

Comment: do I have to import Observables for it to work though?